# Magento Product Images tab does not load

Tags: php, magento

[image: Dashboard product view.]

In my magento dashboard, the product image tab is always empty for all products, the images of these products appear on the frontend. I can't add images to any newly made products

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about your problem ?

Comment: the system attributes 'thumbnail', 'small image','gallery', 'image','media_gallery' do not load in any attribute set, this is the problem.. can you help me out? @Akah